# Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module dx due to:Error: [$compile:baddir] Directive name 'DOMComponent' is invalid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting this error while running the application.
Angular :1.6.8
Jquery : 2.2.4
Bower : 1.8.2

Screen is blank.

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   ftfwebApp due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate
>   module dx due to: Error: [$compile:baddir] Directive name
>   'DOMComponent' is invalid. The first character must be a lowercase
>   letter
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$compile/baddir?p0=DOMComponent
>       at http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
>       at assertValidDirectiveName (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6905:13)
>       at $CompileProvider.registerDirective [as directive] (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6932:7)
>       at runInvokeQueue (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4356:35)
>       at http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4364:11
>       at forEach (http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:336:20)
>       at loadModules

Comment: Show your module

Answer (score 1):

Change your directive name

```
DOMComponent to dom-component
```

You should use dash-separated names inside the html and camelCase for the corresponding name in the directive.